# TFS Branch & Merge

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs, merge

Is this an acceptable scenario for a TFS merge; if so, how do I do the merge:

We have a website which we branched in TFS. The original website, Branch A, was deployed to the Live site. Branch B was modified to run on a newer database structure (CRM system version upgrade).

Development continued on Version A. Some changes were also made on Version B.

Now, I need to get all the changes made to Version A, into Version B, so that Version B still runs on the new CRM database, but includes all the changes made to Version A since the branch.

In TFS merge tool, which is the source & which is the target?

Bonus Question: I've been struggling with this and I'm considering a different approach - can somehow I compare the current Version B with the version at the point of branching, to see which changes were made? There weren't a lot, and I could potentially take a fresh branch of Version A and just copy over the changes. How would I compare two full versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you answered it yourself I guess:

> all the changes made to Version A, into Version B

source = A, target = B

bonus answer: right mouse button on the version b branch folder: compare. Source path = version b, latest version; Target path = version b, select the first changeset (this will be when the branch was created).

Comment: Thanks. re: bonus question, when I created the branch Version B, I didn't check in straight away, so I have as my first changeset a version with some changes. I'd need to compare it to the previous changeset for Version A. That still possible?

Comment: And just to clarify - the merge operation you describe, it's going to update Version B with Version A's changes. It will still leave me with 2 projects. Version A won't have changed, Version B will have the changes. Is that correct?

Comment: re bonus question: yes you can also select the other branch, then select the last changeset of A before you made the branch. second comment: yes that is correct